# Do simultanious runs of a web app create their own instances of an in-process COM? If so why are my results getting mixed up between web app users

Tags: c#, asp.net, com

I am creating a web app using ASP.NET. This web app creates an instance of a C# class. This C# class instantiates a COM component written in c++. The C# class calls multiple functions in the COM dll sending a lot of data (read from an ascii file) through the COM interface. The COM dll then does calculations and returns data to the C# application using structures defined in the COM IDL. The COM dll was originally creating us MS C++6.0 but is now built using VS2012.

I see that when I access the web app from 2 different computers, 2 instances of the C# class are created, as I'd expect. Each instance of the C# class creates an instance of the COM component using "new MyCOMInterface". When I look at each instance of the COM interface, they have different addresses, which is what I'd expect. I then start the calculations on both computers. The initial sets of results that get returned from both runs of the web app are correct on both computers. But, if I then press the "Next" button on computer1 (to get the next set of results, which should be sitting in memory in the COM dll), the new results are display on both computers!

I put the C# class within a Session to try to fix this but it did not work. If I then try to get the "Next" set of results from computer2 (by pressing a "Next" button in the web app on comuter2), the results displayed  are the next results from computer1.

I am trying to determine if this is a problem in the web app or if my 2 instances of the COM dll are not really independent (are they somehow sharing some memory)? I know that when I run my COM component from two different instances of an .exe, all memory is separate, but I don't know if this is true in a web app.

Comment: Please add code, so that the users can see what the issue is..

Answer (score 1):

COM loads and frees libraries using the standard LoadLibrary(Ex) and FreeLibrary routines. These routines load only a single copy of each DLL and maintain a count on the number of times they have been called. When this count reaches 0, the DLL is truly unloaded.

This means that all COM objects served by a DLL (or OCX or other in-process container) will share the global state of their containing library. This is true no matter what isolation is provided by other frameworks like .NET or ASP.NET -- COM doesn't know anything about .NET's AppDomains, for example, and therefore it cannot maintain a separate copy of the DLL per AppDomain.

What you are seeing appears to be bad global state management in your COM DLL. It sounds like it needs to be reimplemented so that the state is managed per object instance.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  When my COM is called from 2 separate executables on one system, the memory for both instances of the COM are totally separate; no memory is shared.  So I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "global state management"?

Comment: A single process has a single memory space. All DLLs are loaded into the isolated memory space for the process loading it. Within each DLL (or EXE or whatever) is a memory management framework such as C++'s new/delete or C's malloc()/free(). This topic is too broad for a comment thread. I recommend you read up on how OS's manage memory on behalf of processes and how language frameworks manage their own heaps within the process memory space.

Comment: Global DLL state would be 1) variables (including variables with types that are C++ classes) that are declared at the file level in your C/C++ and 2) static fields of C++ classes. These "exist" once per load of the DLL -- that is, once per process, not once per object instance.

Comment: I understand memory management within an EXE and within a DLL on a stand alone system or on a network. What I do not know is if multiple runs of a web app each have there own memory space or if some of the memory is shared.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Doesn't matter to COM. If the web apps are all running within the same process (pretty sure that's the case), the DLL will only get loaded once no matter how many object instances you have or how many web apps are using them. If my diagnosis is correct, your object instances are manipulating the same global or static variables.

Comment: Or to answer your OP as separate questions: 1) Your web app instances are running in the same process. 2) COM libraries are ultimately loaded once per process. 3) Your object instances are sharing some common state (global or static) and shouldn't be.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.  It was point 1)  I was not sure about. I was hoping a separate process was created for each instance of the web app (the way, for example  each Terminal Server user runs in his own memory space). We are trying to use a 15 year old COM component on the web and we need each web user to have separate memory for the COM dll. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "One process per request" is how CGI (Common Gateway Interface) works (that's where the "cgi-bin" part of many URLs comes from). That's how websites used to work in UNIX during the web's Pleistocene Era (not sure if that's the case anymore). That also used to be an option in IIS as well (not sure if it's still available) but it has never been how ASP.NET works. "One process per request" is Ok in UNIX which can spawn processes fast, but unacceptably slow in Windows because creating new processes in Windows is very expensive. ASP.NET uses one host process per site.